# Multiple each row of a matrix by the same row of another matrix without for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to multiple each row of a matrix by each corresponding row in another matrix in R. I can do this with a for loop but it's incredibly slow and I'm trying to do this with multiple matrices, each of which is 1.8 million rows.

```
mat1 <- matrix(1:10, nrow=5, ncol=2)
mat2 <- matrix(1:5, nrow=5, ncol=2)

vect <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(mat1)){
  vect[i] <-  sum(mat1[i, ] * t(mat2[i, ]))
}
vect
```

It also works if I use matrix multiplication with a vector

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mat1)){
  vect[i] <-  mat1[i, ] %*% as.vector(t(mat2[i, ]))
}
```

I tried using the `apply()` function but it tries to multiple each row of `mat2` by each row of `mat1` and I can't figure out how to stop that without a `for()` loop.

Speed and memory efficiency are important for me in this case. In theory I could use `dplyr` because I am pulling `mat1` and `mat2` from a dataframe and `vect` could be appended as an additional column. Again, I can't figure out how to do it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague informed me of the `rowSums()` function and it works beautifully in this case.

```
m1 <- as.matrix(select(df[1:10, ], one_of(cov.list$site.ef)))
m2 <- as.matrix(t(select(df[1:10, ], one_of(names(B.site.wide[-1])))))

rowSums(m1 * m2)
```

It worked on my 1.8 million row matrices in under a second.